# KendoUI Window Dynamic Open

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I would like to use the kendoui window to open a dynamic number of windows and ideally if that window already existed by name it would just show the same window.

So i'm imagining a javascript function

```
win(name, url, width)
```

And I would call this from various places

```
<button onclick="win('my window', '/example/view', 100);">click me</button>
```

Im not really sure how to create a window like this using its name and how to check if it already exists.

The app is very simple, a range of menus and each menu opens a window, but the menu is driven from database content, thus I cant predefine all the windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `win` function you should check if you already have that KendoUI window created. If so, you reuse the existing one and open it. Otherwise you create it.

Example:

```
function win (name, url, width) {
    var my_win = $("#" + name).data("kendoWindow");
    if (my_win) {
        // already exist, reuse it
        my_win.open();
    } else {
        // does not exist, create it
        // create a div with id "name" for my window and append it to 
        // to a container ("example") where all the windows are going to be.
        my_win = $("<div id='" + name + "'></div>").kendoWindow({
              title: name,
              content: url,
              width: width,
              appendTo: "#example",
              visible: true
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** For invoking this from an anchor element (`a`) define `win` global to your page and define the anchors as follow.

```
  <a href="javascript: win('id1', '/page1', 200);">Open id1 window</a>
  <a href="javascript: win('id2', '/page2', 200);">Open id2 window</a>
```

Example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/ekIba/2

Comment: Thats pretty darn close. However your binding that to a change of a textfield, how would I call win from a url with a link <a href="???"

Comment: Define the `win` function before and define the `a` as in my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Once KendoUI window open it will create set of HTML elements starting with `<div class="k-widget k-window" data-role="......`. For each window it will create separate set of HTMLs.

So you can filter all those windows with `var kendoeWinElems = $('.k-window')`

And on a loop dig down to the title area (.k-window-title) and compare with the name and title of the window and then call `relaventWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();`

For ease of comparison and filtering I suggest you to add data attributes or classes as needed for buttons and Kendo windows

Hope this help!!!!